# Как обратиться к ячейке в collectionView, которая еще не видна?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit

У меня есть `UICollectionView` с вертикальным скроллом. Мне надо после определённого нажатия на кнопку обратиться к  ячейке, которая не видна на экране (т.к. она находится в нижней части коллекции). Но при таком обращении ячейка равна `nil`.

Каким образом можно организовать обращение к ячейке, которая еще не видна на `collectionView`?

Comment: обращайтесь напрямую к данным на основании которых создается ячейка

Comment: не, ну мне нужно у этой ячейки поменть цвет или UIImage

Comment: я так понимаю, у вас есть какой то массив данных, где хранится информация о том в какой ячейке какая картинка. вот там и меняйте

Comment: Ок, это понятно. Еще один вопрос можно? Я ща хочу сделать scrollToItem. Но когда её вызываю  скрол на конкретную ячейку, то не это не срабатывает, он делает небольшой скролл и тупо возвращается на прежнее место. С таким не сталкивались?

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя обратится к ячейке, которая не видна, так как iOS, ради оптимизации ресурсов, не создает сразу все ячейки, так как они занимают много места в памяти для `tableView`/`collectionView`. Можно обратится к ячейке, либо при создании в `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, либо перед появлением на экране в `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`. Лучше во втором, так как рекомендуется "насетапливать" UI именно в нем.